# Allow backstack to fill with dozens of reinstantiated activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, back, back-stack

This a straightforward question but I can't find any clear information to help me make my decision.

I have an application with 2 forms (2 activities) that are filled in for a given object, cleared and then filled in for the next object. This maybe be done more than 100 times during a run of the given application. So the backstack could be populated with 100+ activities.

All that data is saved into an sqlite database, so should I be allowing the backstack to fill like that? What are the performance implications - storing hundreds of instances of a form would surely start to take a toll. Are these instances stored efficiently enough that I don't have to worry about this, or does the backstack have some sort of limit anyway? Is there any way to make the backstack store just the entered data, or is the saved "instance" composed of nothing more than the entered data anyway? Is querying an sqlite database onbackpressed instead  that much less efficient than allowing the backstack to load previous forms? Is there a way to reload an existing instance ala `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` and clear the existing entered data, but save it (the data) in the backstack?

I have constantly been reading/told that it is a bad idea to modify the behaviour of the back button, backstack and activity management of android, which makes me tentative about doing so as an android novice.

I reckon the data from both forms would be no more in size than the 2nd paragraph of this question fyi.

Thank you for your help.

EDIT in response to JoxTraex:

`fill -> add -> fill -> add -> n -> commit`

could then be

`fill activity A and then instantiate and fill B -> transact to DB -> REinstantiate and fill A then REinstantiate and fill B -> transact to DB -> n -> commit`

have I understood correctly?

If so reloading rather than instantiating a new instance of A and B should solve the backstack problem as there will only be ever 2 activities in it.

Which leads to confusion about what `onbackpressed` will do - will it reload previously entered data or work no more than twice as there were just 2 activities in the backstack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **not** use the stack to trace the data **nor** should you have 100 instance of an activity!

You should instead load the data from the database dynamically as needed. Also if you have that activity being done 100 times, then you already have a problem with your design, make it easier so that the user doesn't have to do this pattern:

```
fill -> commit -> fill -> commit
```

Instead change it to just:

```
fill -> add -> fill -> add -> N -> commit
```

This way you simplify your design and make more effective use of your form.

`fill` in my case, is filling ALL respective data (ideally on one screen) `add` means push that data into the transaction and `commit` means to finish the transaction and push everything. `N` means to repeat the `fill -> add` pattern. After completing the transaction go back to your main menu/view of the new respective data. Also I would recommend to instead have a ListView that is populated with all the entries instead of using the stack of activities.

Comment: `fill` constitutes going between 2 activities as the form wouldn't fit on 1 screen, so it would be nice to save a trail of just 1 form to the backstack. Also means that the activities will have to be reinstantiated 100s of times....Are you saying query and/or fill (`add` to) the database even when navigating between form A and form B? Also what do you mean by `commit`?  Given that I have 2 forms, would it be a good idea to turn the backstack off and just depend on the database? (Overriding the back button to make it do the corresponding database operations instead)

Comment: `fill` in my case, is filling ALL respective data (ideally on one screen) `add` means push that data into the transaction and `commit` means to finish the transaction and push everything. `N` means to repeat the `fill -> add` pattern. After completing the transaction go back to your main menu/view of the new respective data. Also I would recommend to instead have a ListView that is populated with all the entries instead of using the stack of activities.

Comment: Ah. `fill -> add -> fill -> add -> n -> commit` could be then `fill activity A and then instantiate and fill B -> transact to DB -> REinstantiate and fill A then REinstantiate and fill B -> transact to DB -> n -> commit` - have I understood correctly? If so reloading rather than instantiating a new instance of A and B should solve the backstack problem as there will only be ever 2 activities in it. Which leads to confusion about what `onbackpressed` will do - will it reload previously entered data or work no more than twice as there were just 2 activities in the backstack?

Comment: Sure if you want to approach it like that, that would work. You need to think about after you have all your N entries what do you want to do. Ideally pressing back should do something that is intuitive. For instance pressing back on either A or B causes going back to the previous screen so that the current transaction data can be changed. before it is committed. Ideally you should have a button to view that data as it is on one of the screens, ignoring the current transaction or you could keep it. It comes down to user flow and how you want to set it up. The less the better.

Comment: How else might one approach it? I'm intersted to know. Actually I do have button that goes back to form A, and I could override the back to act like this button. Not sure what you mean when you say "ignoring the current transaction or you could keep it" though. Sorry for being so finickity...

Comment: The view button would basically just go to the list of all the data and the current transaction could either be A) dropped or B) saved. Ideally you should save it and allow the user to return to the old transaction by using the back button WHILE on the list screen, so that the original flow can be maintained.

Comment: I understand. A view button is def. something I plan to include, autosaving the current entry, but first I'd like to get the user flow control right. Thinking about other approaches, a better way would be perhaps using a single activity with a form A activity fragment and a form B activity fragment, which you get to using  tabs. Then "back" can just go back to the previous set of forms, rather than self contained activity B. This seems to simplify flow control. But I'm interested to know else one might approach flow control - or is there "no right answer", beyond keeping it simple/intuitive?